# Conditionally setting a href attribute with vueJS

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

```
 <tr v-for="(i, index) in streams">
                            <td class="text-center">{{index + 1}}</td>
                            <td class="text-center">{{i.title}}</td>
                            <td class="text-center"><label class="label" v-bind:class="{ 'label-danger' : i.stateIndex === 0, 'label-warning' : i.stateIndex === 1, 'label-success' : i.stateIndex === 2 }">{{i.state}}</label></td>
                            <td class="text-center link"><a v-bind:href="i.link" target="_blank"><i v-bind:class="i.streamingPlatformClass"></i></a></td>
                            <td class="text-center">{{i.userId}}</td>
                            <td class="text-center">{{i.streamingPlatformID}}</td>
                            <td class="text-center"><button v-on:click="removeStream(i.id)" class="btn btn-primary manageStreamButton">Remove</button><button v-on:click="stopStream(i.id)" v-if="i.stateIndex != 2" class="btn btn-primary manageStreamButton">Stop</button></td>
                        </tr>
```

In the TD with class "link", I'm trying to conditionally set a href attribute.
The "link" property in streams is either a youtube link or an  tag with a FB video source. The idea is to make it a clickable link when the link property has a youtube link AND to disable the href attribute when the link property has an  tag so it's not clickable.
So far I've managed to conditionally alter the href attribute but it still remains clickable and with a link.
I know it can be done with onclick return false, but I'm looking for another way.
Or if it's possible to remove the  tag conditionally, that would be a great solution aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the tag conditionally with a v-if. It does mean duplicating your icon code;

```
<td class="text-center link">
    <a v-if="showLink" v-bind:href="i.link" target="_blank"><i v-bind:class="i.streamingPlatformClass"></i></a>
    <i v-if="!showLink"  v-bind:class="i.streamingPlatformClass"></i>
</td>
```

Comment: Thank you, I did exactly this a moment before you posted it :) I'm glad somebody else thinks that's a decent solution, because I mostly come up with unnecessarily comples ones :) Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

There are several options to do this. I think the best one is to switch between an `<a>` and another tag, for example `<span>`.

```
<a v-if="shouldLink" v-bind:href="i.link">Link</a>
<span v-else>Link</span>
```

Other ways could include setting the `href` to something like `javascript:void()` to disable the linking or adding a CSS class with `pointer-events: none` to prevent clicking on the link.